# Sending email to all admins upon user sign up in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have followed the ruby on rails tutorial in my design of a web app and am now venturing off on my own to add in some functionality that isn't covered in the tutorial.

Currently, I am trying to send an email to all users with the admin role. The admin role is implemented in the tutorial as a boolean field admin on the user model. I tried to do this by the following method:

When `@user.send_activation_email` is called in the create method in user_controller.rb, it goes to the definition in user.rb

```
def send_activation_email
  UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  UserMailer.user_signed_up(self).deliver_now # my modified code
end
```

I created `user_signed_up` in the user_mailer.rb

```
def user_signed_up(user)
  @user = user
  # Send email to all admins that user has signed up
  User.find_by_admin("true") do |admin|
    mail to: admin.email, subject: "A new user has signed up"
  end
end
```

but when I test this functionality in the user_mailer_test.rb with

```
test "user_signed_up" do
  user = users(:archer)
  mail = UserMailer.user_signed_up(user)
  assert_equal "A new user has signed up", mail.subject
  User.find_by_admin("true") do |admin|
    assert_equal [admin.email], mail.to
    assert_equal ["noreply@example.com"], mail.from
  end
end
```

I get that the tests fails on `assert_equal "A new user has signed up", mail.subject`. It looks like all that works, but it never enters the do loop of administrators. Am I querying the database incorrectly? Is there a better way to do this? I found this, but I'm not sure how to implement it

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: Proc.new { Admin.pluck(:email) },
          from: 'notification@example.com'

  def new_registration(user)
    @user = user
    mail(subject: "New User Signup: #{@user.email}")
  end
end
```

Would that be a better choice?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it "never enters the do loop of administrators" because `User.find_by_admin("true")` isn't returning any records, i.e. there are no administrators to loop through. Did you perhaps mean `User.find_by_admin(true)`?

Regardless, I think you're approaching this wrong: You should just send one email to e.g. `admins@example.com` and have that mailbox forward all messages to all of your admins.

Comment: I like your second way, but I still need to query the database to get all of the admin users in order to create a list of emails to forward to. Switching from `"true"` to `true` didn't change anything.